# Can I use an OpenCart 1.5.x theme on OpenCart version 2.x?

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

I got a beautiful opencart theme for opencart version 1.5.6.x. But I like the new opencart version 2.3.x. I want to know if there is a way I can use the theme on the new opencart? I installed it but got some errors.
Thank you.

Comment: No, It will not work. You must need to use theme compatible with OpenCart version 2.3.x.

Answer (score 0):

If you're able, do it by hand.  Copy the needed elements from the stylesheet and add the class calls into the template.

Not impossible, but would take some time.

I'm finding OpenCart to be extremely inflexible between versions; even many 2.3.0.2 mods won't work on 2.3.0.2_rc (technically the same version, but one is meant for 'testing' / bug spotting).

So installing a theme or mod from a major version change would not be worth the effort troubleshooting the errors.

Start fresh, do it by hand if you're really into the theme.